# What is the difference between various levels of data

Tags: cobol

what is concept of the picture clause in  COBOL language and why this is important?

```
01 X PIC 9(3) VALUE 2 
   05 Y PIC 9(3) VALUE 3
```

what is meaning of level ( 01 ) in this, how 01 is differ from 05.

Comment: Please check the answer and have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - please either comment about unclear parts or vote + accept.

Answer (score 4):

So basically everything in COBOL is a "chunk" of data. The way you defines your variables determines how they can be accessed in the program. Anytime you see the levels of variable get higher you are dealing with group variables so here is an example of the difference between elementary variables and group variables.

```
01 WS-DATE PIC X(10) VALUE '2017-11-24'.
```

this is an elementary item because there are no higher level variables under it. I can take this same date field and make it a group item by changing my variable definitions

```
01 WS-DATE
   05 WS-YEAR  PIC X(4) VALUE '2017'.
   05 FILLER   PIC X    VALUE '-'.
   05 WS-MONTH PIC XX   VALUE '11'.
   05 FILLER   PIC X    VALUE '-'.
   05 WS-DAY   PIC XX   VALUE '24'.
```

So now in my program, I have more options. I can now use any part of that date as well as the whole date. If I `DISPLAY WS-DATE` it will display the whole date, but I could now display just the year, month or day because of how I structured the working storage.

So basically if you reference a data item, you are actually taking that along with every higher level data item below it.

**So to answer your question**, there really isn't a difference between the levels. They really just dictate the data structure (with the exception of 88 level variables which are used as flags).

Now back to your original example. Your example actually fails compile because you cannot have a group data item with a picture clause. The picture clause defines the data as numeric, alphanumeric, national ect... so when you make a group level item, there can be any combination and size of data item below it. The "correct" way to write your example would be either:

```
01 X PIC 9(3) VALUE 2.
01 Y PIC 9(3) VALUE 3.
```

or

```
01 WS-STUFF.
   05 X PIC 9(3) VALUE 2.
   05 Y PIC 9(3) VALUE 3.
```

or maybe

```
01 X PIC 9(3) VALUE 2.
01 Y.
   05 FILLER PIC 9(3) VALUE 3.
```

They could all be used to achieve the same thing, so which one you use will really depend on the data you expect to be using in the program.

Comment: nice explanation Saggingrufus .can you ex plane what is difference between . if i give elementary items level 05 or 10 in a group items what is difference between them , is any effect of the number if some one use firstly    05  x pic 9(2) value 2   and second one is      10 x pic 9(2)  value 2 how the differ

Comment: The difference is how you can use the data. In my second example, if I were to DISPLAY WS-STUFF this is what would be displayed: 002003 but if I only displayed X the value would be 002. So a group level variable contains every high level beneath it. So there is no difference between the numbers. It only shows how the data is structured.

Comment: you can, but most people go up in increments of 5  so 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, but any level between those will also work

Comment: i face a problem .

Comment: @vivek - The levels 5, 10, 15 is just a convention, which allows you to insert new levels in between if needed. Was kind of important when Cobol was new and the program was on punched cards that couldn't be edited.